# Is it possible to configure a rule in Azure ACS so that I can match a claim value with a wildcard/regular expression?

Tags: .net, azure, identity

See attached screenshot, I'm trying to create a rule that allows me to control who gets the Administrator role based on the domain of their email address from the google identity provider.

This seems like it should be pretty straight forward; the google apps OAuth provider should probably provide the domain for it's google apps accounts, but as it doesn't at the moment I want to do some sort of wildcard match on the email address.

It's straightforward to handle it in the relying party application, but I'm trying to externalise the identity management function.

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. Were you able to solve it? I also tried to add 4 different email addresses with comma seperation, but it does not work. Can there only be one email address in the Input Claim value: Enter Value: TextBox?

Comment: No, it doesn't seem like it's possible in the current version of ACS, maybe in a later version.  In the mean time you'd have to keep that logic local to the application, or possibly implement an additional custom intermediary claims processor.

Answer (score 0):

The rules engine in ACS is very simple and I don't believe you can do this today. You can do further transformations on the app as you say. The place to write this is probably in the ***ClaimsAuthorizationManager***. Even though it is "in the app side", it would still be well encapsulated and separated from your code.